# Why am I getting "list index out of range"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to Python, and I have a Python function that's supposed to get the HTML from a Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cities_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population) and, for the purposes of this question, get the HTML in the first column in each row. I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup4.

```
def getStates():
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cities_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("tbody") 
rows = table.findAll("tr")

for row in rows:
    columns = row.findAll("td")
    print(columns[0])
```

The "columns" variable should be a list, which I know because:

1. `print(columns)` gives me multiple lists of HTML (because of the for loop) enclosed in square brackets and commas.
2. `print(len(columns))` returns "9", meaning there's 9 columns in each row, which can be confirmed by counting the columns in the Wikipedia page.
3. The `findAll()` function returns a list, as shown in the BS4 documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

However, if I do `print(columns[0])`, or any index, I get the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. And so, can someone give me any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm making an obvious mistake here but trying to search up this problem didn't yield any results.

Comment: Because `columns` is an empty list... presumably because there are no td tags in that row

Comment: Like I said, if I did "print(len(columns))" it returns 9, which means the list is not empty.

Comment: Ahh, crap. You were right. For some reason the very first list is empty, I'm an idiot, thanks. I literally spent a few hours stuck on this, so that's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know it's been a while, but feel free to make your comment an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a list of lists, but as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, I didn't realize the first list (in index 0) was empty.